Test suite failed to run ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

I am trying to test my project using a mock API instead of a real one to save money. However, when I add the following code to my setupTests.js file:
// setupTests.js
import { server } from "./mocks/server";

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

I get this error:
Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

      1 | // mocks/server.js
    > 2 | import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
        | ^
      3 | import { handlers } from './handlers'; // your request handlers
      4 |
      5 | export const server = setupServer(...handlers);



What We Tried:

Polyfill for TextEncoder and TextDecoder:

We tried adding a polyfill for TextEncoder and TextDecoder in the setupTests.js file.
Code added:
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('util');
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;




Ensured Jest Environment is jsdom:

We checked and ensured that the Jest environment is set to jsdom to simulate a browser-like environment.
Jest configuration:
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setupTests.js'],
};




Updated Dependencies:

We updated all dependencies to their latest versions to ensure compatibility.
Command used:
npm update




Verified Mock Server Setup:

We ensured the mock server setup in mocks/server.js was correct.
Example:
// mocks/server.js
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { handlers } from './handlers';

export const server = setupServer(...handlers);




Created a Minimal Test Case:

We created a minimal test case to isolate the problem.
Test code:
// src/__tests__/example.test.js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => <div>Hello, World!</div>;

test('renders hello world', () => {
  render(<TestComponent />);
  expect(screen.getByText('Hello, World!')).toBeInTheDocument();
});





What We Expected:

Polyfill for TextEncoder and TextDecoder:

We expected adding the polyfill to make TextEncoder and TextDecoder available in the Node.js environment, resolving the error.


Jest Environment as jsdom:

We expected using the jsdom environment to simulate a browser-like environment where TextEncoder and TextDecoder would be available.


Updated Dependencies:

We expected updating dependencies to resolve any compatibility issues that might be causing the error.


Verified Mock Server Setup:

We expected ensuring the correct setup of the mock server to eliminate any configuration issues.


Minimal Test Case:

We expected the minimal test case to help identify if there were any fundamental issues with the setup.





Are using this anywhere in your test files ?
/**

@jest-environment jsdom
*/

